# dividing my dataset (csv format) using Stratified k-fold sampling and saving the output of each fold in separate csv file.

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, sampling

My dataset has around 5000 samples and 3 classes (one hot encoded) and I am interested in creating samples using stratified K fold. Moreover, in the end, I want to split each output file (from the K fold) into train and test.

I tried the following suggestion from sklearn documentation but I want to retain the shape of my dataset.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits(X, y)

print(sss)       

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```